# What is the best practice for initial a function for new item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I run the code the like this.

```
// only initial for new item
var columnSplitter = {
    config: {
        $col: $('.col'),
        loopStart: 0
    },

    init: function(){
        for(var i=columnSplitter.config.loopStart; i<columnSplitter.config.$col.length; i++){
            columnSplitter.config.$col.eq(i).css({'border-radius': '1000px'});
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}

columnSplitter.init();
columnSplitter.config.loopStart = -1;

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var contentString = "<div class='col' />";
    $('.test').append(contentString);

    columnSplitter.config.loopStart++
    columnSplitter.config.$col = $('.test .col');
    columnSplitter.init();
});
```

Each time when I click the button it only fire once for the new item instead of loop all of the items. Which I think will be better.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZQjKX?editors=1011

In case 2

```
// always start from 0 means it will loop all of the item
var columnSplitter = {
    config: {
        $col: $('.col'),
        loopStart: 0
    },

    init: function(){
        for(var i=0; i<columnSplitter.config.$col.length; i++){
            columnSplitter.config.$col.eq(i).css({'border-radius': '1000px'});
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}

columnSplitter.init();

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var contentString = "<div class='col' />";
    $('.test').append(contentString);

    columnSplitter.config.$col = $('.test .col');
    columnSplitter.init();
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opErgR?editors=1011

each times when I click the button it will loop from old item to new items, which I think is this will make the performance lower?

So what is the best practice in initial a function in this kind of case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need such loop structures to apply some logic to each element (old and new)? oO I think much easier for understanding will be something like this:

```
var container = $('.test');
var items = container.find('.col');

function applyElementChanges(item) {
    item.css({ 'border-radius': '1000px' });
}

items.each(function(i, q) {
    q = $(q);
    applyElementChanges(q);
});

$('.btn').on('click', function(){
    var newCol = $('<div class="col"></div>');
    container.append(newCol);
    applyElementChanges(newCol);
});
```

Comment: Ops, yeah, this is much simple and easier understand. =-=||| Thanks dude, I think I am overthinking.

Comment: No problems! Glad to help!)